# Mturk: transfer HIT from Sandbox to Production site

Tags: amazon-web-services, mechanicalturk

If I create a HIT in the Sandbox via Mturk's GUI, is it possible to transfer it to the Production site, or do I have to re-create the HIT manually in the Production site?

In particular, is it possible, to download .input, .question and .properties for HIT created via GUI in the sandbox, in order to use them to generate the same HIT on the Production site via the CLT?

The obvious way seems to be using [Mturk HIT's layouts](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_HITLayoutParameterArticle.html). However, reading the doc, I don't see how/ know whether it is possible to to do this using the CLT. The doc on `HITLayoutParameter` requires using `CreateHIT`, but this is not an available command in the CLT (only have `loadHITs`).

I have seen other questions [Creating mTurk HIT from Layout with parameters using boto and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29202837/creating-mturk-hit-from-layout-with-parameters-using-boto-and-python) and [Create a MTurk HIT from an existing template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14592338/create-a-mturk-hit-from-an-existing-template) about ways to do it with `boto` but I am still wondering whether that's doable with the CLT.

Comment: The HITLayoutIds are also tied to the separate sandbox and live servers, so that won't work either. In general, CLTs are best avoided as they only cover a minority of available features of MTurk.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The live and sandbox modes are completely separate and no transfer is possible from one to the other.

You will need to implement this programmatically by storing the specs of the sandbox HIT and creating a live HIT.

Another option is to use a service like TurkPrime.com which allows you to copy HITs from sandbox to live mode